# pass data to themeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have a problem whit ThemeProvider in my nextjs project.
I wounder what is the best way to pass data to the theme.
In my getInitialProps inside the `/pages/index` I get the setting data, and the ThemeProvider tag is in `/pages/_app.js` wrapper `<Component />`.. how can I pass the data from index to _app? any idea?
Thanksss!!

here is my code:

**/pages/_app.js**

```
import App from "next/app";
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

/* Styles */
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import theme from "../styles/theme/primary";

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>  // Here ThemeProvider whit theme
          <Header />
          <Container>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Container>
          <Footer />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

**pages/index.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

/* Others */
import { getData } from "../helper/api";

const Index = props => {
  const res = props.data;

  return (
    <>
      <Home data={res} />
    </>
  );
};

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ res }) => {
  try {
    let req = await getData(); // Here I get the settings. 
    return { data: req };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
    return { data: null};
  }
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: why did not you call `getData()` in `getInitialProps` in `_app.js`?

Comment: mmm because I have two more pages whit one endpoint each and I read that its not recommendable do the fecth in _app.js in this case. Now my 3 pages have a getInitialProps whit his own data.

Comment: not sure, i think `pages/index.js` always run after `/pages/_app.js` so you can not pass data from pages to `_app`

Comment: so in `_app.js`, add condition if `ctx.pathname` equal `'/'`  you can `getData()`  in `getInitialProps`

Comment: I try your example, and it dosen 't work.. I mean works the getInitialProps inside _app but fails de getInitialProps inside index